# How to make edges of a graph thicker?

Tags: r, igraph

I have made a graph using 'igraph' library and function 'graph.formula' but the edges appearing are really light in color. How can I make the lines dark/bold?

Comment: Could you give a data/plot example?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which graph you want from the igraph package. Here is an example that comes from the following [tutorial](http://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html) . You can adapt the parameter edge.width:

```
g <- barabasi.game(100)
plot(g, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, vertex.size=4,
 vertex.label.dist=0.5, vertex.color="red", edge.arrow.size=0.5, edge.width=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play a little with the following parameters:

```
edge.width = 5, # adjust thickness
edge.color = rgb(0,0.5,0.5,0.1), # color and opacity
edge.curved = TRUE # logical, curved edges
```